# Como crear texto en la posición del ratón

Tags: javascript

Trato de escribir sobre el navegador las coordenadas en las que se encuentra el ratón. Esto sólo me va creando un h5 y mi objetivo es que lo cree en las coordenadas del ratón
y vaya borrando el registro anterior

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script>
    let ref = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
    ref[0].addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        
        let caja=document.createElement("h5");
        caja.innerText=`${e.screenX} ${e.clientY}`;
        document.body.appendChild(caja);
        })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu objetivo es añadir un `h5` justo en la posición actual del ratón en el `DOM`, puedes leer las coordenadas del mouse en el evento `mousemove`, que ofrece la posición exacta del ratón en las propiedades `clientX` y `clientY`.

Luego añades un h5 con `position: fixed;` y con las coordenadas del mouse, para que quede justo en la posición donde está el ratón.

Te adjunto un demo que puedes ejecutar en vivo si estás en un navegador.

```js
var caja = document.createElement("h5");
document.body.appendChild(caja);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => { 
        caja.innerText=`${e.screenX} ${e.clientY}`;
        caja.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        caja.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
        })
```

```css
h5{
 position:fixed;
 cursor: default;
//transform: translateY(-100%); 
}
```

Si por otro lado, solo quieres actualizar un h5 en una posición fija, simplemente actualiza el texto del `h5` en cada evento:

```js
let caja=document.createElement("h5");
document.body.appendChild(caja);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {       
        caja.innerText=`${e.screenX} ${e.clientY}`; 
        })
```